# Final year project ideas - complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, big-list

For my final year, I have to do a project for a module. I want to investigate something in the complex analysis area. I've only covered the basics of analysis, like Cauchy's IT/IF, residue theorem etc. The only thing that's been suggested so far is the mathematics of Aerofoils. Just wondering if anyone has ideas of areas I could look at?

Comment: Converted to a Wiki since it is asking for a list of ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you to look at some special functions, i.e., gamma function, zeta function and theta function. And the connection between cplx analysis and number theory. It's really interesting that the property of these functions will lead to some property of prime numbers. You can especially focus on the fundamental theorem of prime numbers and the four square theorem.

Comment: I've not studied those before, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at the book of E.M.Stein.

Comment: ... and Rami Shakarchi; there are two authors to that book.

Comment: @BritMiller: Dear Brit, The book *Riemann's zeta function*, by Edwards, gives a very nice exposition of the zeta-function, and related topics such as the Gamma function.  It also discusses a lot of interesting topics in analysis that you don't often see in courses, such as Mellin transforms, Euler--Maclaurin summation, and asymptotic expansions.  Regards,

Comment: Thank you all, I'll take a look.

Comment: @Willie Wong♦ Thank you, sometimes I omit the second name because I think it won't cause any confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest studying Fourier and Laplace transforms. Learning them well will suit you in the future, regardless of which field you end up in.

Comment: There is a tutor who runs a project on both of these, but she said they weren't particularly challenging and generally for people aiming for a 2:1; she suggested I try something more challenging.

Answer (score 3):

The theory of minimal surfaces is kind of interesting, there are a lot of nice pictures out there of the strange shapes you can make. Learning about the Poisson kernel and seeing how it works is interesting too.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I always found the [Schwarz-Christoffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping) map to be particularly fascinating and always an area of active interest.  The applications are boundless, but really they are used for solving flow-type problems around awful, polygonal boundaries.

Comment: Excellent, that looks very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The [uniformization/Riemann mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) theorem should give you lots to chew on.

Comment: If you can read French, don't miss the book [Uniformisation des surfaces de Riemann - Retour sur un théorème centenaire](http://www.lcdpu.fr/livre/?GCOI=27000100107890). The [PDF](http://www.lcdpu.fr/livre/?GCOI=27000100107890&fa=complements) is freely available.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10516/uniformization-theorem-for-riemann-surfaces.

Comment: These are exactly the sort of things I was looking for; thank you!

Comment: @B11: if you have another question, please use the [Ask Question link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) near the top right of the page.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly less well-known example is the actual *proof* of the [Runge phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon). It is one of my favourite applications of the residue theorem. You can find a sketch of the proof [in this document](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=2926) with links to other resources.

In the same vein, [Lax and Zalcman's book](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=ULECT-58) contains a lot of very interesting examples that one usually do not encounter during a first course in complex analysis.

Comment: Thank you, I've not seen the proof, I'll read through it.

Answer (score 2):

You may find some inspiration in Needham's [Visual Complex Analysis](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca/).

Comment: Library has it in stock, I'll take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you choose, make *sure* it really interests you. You will spend a lot of time on the subject, if you hate it after a week or so, you are in trouble... Pick something reasonably wide, so you have space to move around.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of picking something I could carry on at MSc level (if I manage to get funding!), so going to spend the next couple of months researching different areas.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that complex function and color domain are interesting topics. I was thinking about its application in certain software. For example Blender is one of them that uses the model RGB for designing complex diagrams…

Comment: you could visit this: http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/en/math/groups/ag-geom/publications/db/lifteddomaincoloring.pdf